# Использование bat в Mysql. Быстрое выполнение команд

Tags: mysql, bat

Имеется текстовый файл:

---

Create database my_diplom;

Use my_diplom;

Create table vigruzka (User_Name0 varchar(20) not null, Name0 varchar(20) not null, DisplayName0 varchar(255) not null, Publisher0 varchar(60) not null, Version0 varchar(30) null, LastW datetime, IP_Adress varchar(12) not null);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/SCCM.csv' INTO TABLE vigruzka FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'IGNORE 1 ROWS;

---

Он с расширением *.bat. Что необходимо дописать чтобы он выполнял все команды в Mysql

Comment: _Он с расширением *.bat._ Измените расширение на .SQL и посмотрите справку MySQL по команде SOURCE.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: Ну и https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: А как сделать это через Бат, а то с этим не могу

Comment: Все понял как использовать, еще раз спасибо